# Binding precalculated grouping & subtotal result from SQL to Data grid in UI (Kendo / Wijmo)

Tags: kendo-grid, wijmo-grid

I have situation that I need to do the grouping, subtotal and grand total from SQL side itself. I will be passing the SQL result (including grouping and totals) to UI. Now i have problem with how to bind the result in UI with pagination and grouping option available with Grids.

If i have the raw data from SQL, then I can do the grouping and totals in Grids which displays nice having option to drilldown / drill up values. But in the scenario of having the totals from SQL I'm not able to bind with grouping option.